# componentType error Category Attribute

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, category-attribute

I'm using Magento 2.1.8 fresh install. I'm trying to get my mega-menu options in the category section. **Now i get this error when going to the category page :**

```
> 1 exception(s): Exception #0
> (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The configuration
> parameter "componentType" is a required for "mega-menu" component.
> 
> Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException): The
> configuration parameter "componentType" is a required for "mega-menu"
> component.
> #0 /data/sites/web/demoehaleeu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(361):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array,
> Array, true)
> #1 /data/sites/web/demoehaleeu/www/vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/UiComponentFactory.php(272):
> Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponentFactory->mergeMetadataItem(Array,
> Array, true)
```

I add them like this :

**Di.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider" type="Designit\MegaMenu2\Model\Category\DataProvider" />
</config
```

Deleting this preference does clear out the error but i'm not sure if it will still work.

**DataProvider :**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

namespace Designit\MegaMenu2\Model\Category;

/**
 * Class DataProvider
 *
 * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.CouplingBetweenObjects)
 */
class DataProvider extends \Magento\Catalog\Model\Category\DataProvider
{
    /**
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getFieldsMap()
    {
        return [
            'general' =>
                [
                    'parent',
                    'path',
                    'is_active',
                    'include_in_menu',
                    'name',
                ],
            'content' =>
                [
                    'image',
                    'description',
                    'landing_page',
                ],
            'display_settings' =>
                [
                    'display_mode',
                    'is_anchor',
                    'available_sort_by',
                    'use_config.available_sort_by',
                    'default_sort_by',
                    'use_config.default_sort_by',
                    'filter_price_range',
                    'use_config.filter_price_range',
                ],
            'search_engine_optimization' =>
                [
                    'url_key',
                    'url_key_create_redirect',
                    'use_default.url_key',
                    'url_key_group',
                    'meta_title',
                    'meta_keywords',
                    'meta_description',
                ],
            'assign_products' =>
                [
                ],
            'design' =>
                [
                    'custom_use_parent_settings',
                    'custom_apply_to_products',
                    'custom_design',
                    'page_layout',
                    'custom_layout_update',
                ],
            'schedule_design_update' =>
                [
                    'custom_design_from',
                    'custom_design_to',
                ],
            'category_view_optimization' =>
                [
                ],
            'category_permissions' =>
                [
                ],
            'mega-menu' =>
                [
                    'enable_megamenu',
                    'megamenu_columns',
                    'megamenu_labels'
                ],
        ];
    }
}
```

Not entirely sure what this adds since i can't find docs but it seemed necessary to me. Can someone explain this?

**I install the data like this (InstallData) :**

```
<?php

namespace Designit\Megamenu2\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Module\Setup\Migration;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Setup\CategorySetupFactory;


class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{

    private $categorySetupFactory;

    public function __construct(CategorySetupFactory $categorySetupFactory)
    {
        $this->categorySetupFactory = $categorySetupFactory;
    }


    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $installer = $setup;

        $installer->startSetup();

        $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId);

        $menu_attributes = ['enable_megamenu' => [
            'type' => 'int',
            'label' => 'Enable Mega Menu',
            'input' => 'boolean',
            'source' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Boolean',
            'visible' => true,
            'default' => '0',
            'required' => false,
            'sort_order' => 100,
            'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
            'group' => 'Mega Menu',
            ],
            'megamenu_columns' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Number of Columns',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Designit\MegaMenu2\Model\Attribute\Columns',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 101,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'Mega Menu',
            ],
            'megamenu_labels' => [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Category Label',
                'input' => 'select',
                'source' => 'Designit\MegaMenu2\Model\Attribute\Labels',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 102,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'Mega Menu'
            ]
        ];


        foreach ($menu_attributes as $item => $data) {
            $categorySetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Category::ENTITY, $item, $data);
        }

        $idg = $categorySetup->getAttributeGroupId($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, 'Mega Menu');

        foreach ($menu_attributes as $item => $data) {
            $categorySetup->addAttributeToGroup(
                $entityTypeId,
                $attributeSetId,
                $idg,
                $item,
                $data['sort_order']
            );
        }

        $installer->endSetup();
    }
}
```

This is confusing with the docs. I'm adding my own attribute group and i do not see to find any documentation about adding a new group. However i do know that Eavcategory is not used since 2.1.0 even though it still says it in the docs.

And last but not least i have my XML to show them in the page :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="designit_megamenu">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Mega Menu</item>
                <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">100</item>
                <item name="componentType" xsi:type="string">fieldset</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <field name="enable_megamenu">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">1</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">boolean</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">checkbox</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Enable MegaMenu</item>
                    <item name="prefer" xsi:type="string">toggle</item>
                    <item name="valueMap" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="true" xsi:type="string">1</item>
                        <item name="false" xsi:type="string">0</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="megamenu_columns">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Designit\MegaMenu2\Model\Attribute\Columns</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">2</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Number of Columns</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
        <field name="megamenu_labels">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Designit\MegaMenu2\Model\Attribute\Labels</item>
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">3</item>
                    <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Category Label</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I know that Magento has changed a lot about this in the last couple of versions but any help at all with this error with really help me out!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by just not using another DataProvider. Doesn't seem to have disadvantages to far.